# using replace I want to change row 2 'B' to 'C'

Tags: python, dataframe

Help me to change the only one B to change C

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Student': ['A','B','B','D','E','F'],
                          'maths': [50,60,75,85,64,24],
                          'sci':[25,34,68,58,75,64],
                          'sco':[36,49,58,63,85,96]})
     


Student maths   sci sco
0   A   50  25  36
1   B   60  34  49
2   B   75  68  58
3   D   85  58  63
4   E   64  75  85
5   F   24  64  96

df.replace('B','C') # it is changing both B values
```

using replace I want to change row 2 'B' to 'C'

Comment: Well you have to index on that specific row to update its value, have you checked pandas' docs on [Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)?

Comment: You cannot use `replace` to substitute only one value based on no condition at all.. You should change the value by indexing that particular cell in the dataframe. Something like `df.loc[2, 'Student'] = 'C'` should be useful for you

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `df.at` function. Try using this code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Student': ['A','B','B','D','E','F'],
                          'maths': [50,60,75,85,64,24],
                          'sci':[25,34,68,58,75,64],
                          'sco':[36,49,58,63,85,96]})

df.at[2, "Student"]= "C"

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use also iloc to select the row to change :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Student': ['A','B','B','D','E','F'],
                          'maths': [50,60,75,85,64,24],
                          'sci':[25,34,68,58,75,64],
                          'sco':[36,49,58,63,85,96]})    
df.iloc[2,:] = df.iloc[2,'Student'].replace('B','C')
print(df)
#  Student  maths  sci  sco
#0       A     50   25   36
#1       B     60   34   49
#2       C     75   68   58
#3       D     85   58   63
#4       E     64   75   85
#5       F     24   64   96
```